# Наследование или DI Singleton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, best-practice, ninject

Имеется класс для post, get запросов:

```
public class ExternalCommunicationManager
{
    private string _serverUrl;

    public ExternalCommunicationManager()
    {
        _serverUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUrl"];
    }

    public async Task<IRestResponse> PostRequest(string url, string data, string token = null)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_serverUrl + url);
        var request = CreateRestRequest(Method.POST, token);
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        // execute the request
        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        return response;
    }    
...
    private static RestRequest CreateRestRequest(Method method, string token)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Method = method,
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            Timeout = 30000
        };
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Так же есть несколько классов которые через ninject инджектятся как InSingletonScope

PaymentManager,
UserManager,
и тд.

Собственно вопрос, как лучше и правильнее, наследовать класс который делает запросы и вызывать методы родительского класса, или же инджектить его тоже как SingletonScope внутрь этих менеджеров в конструктор и там вызывать через private field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - не наследовать, и не делать синглтоном. Просто инжектить как зависимость.

Обоснование:

- Необходимости в наследовании нет. У ExternalCommunicationManager умеет отправлять строчку на заданный url. Достаточно очевидно, что UserManager не должен позволять отправлять через себя вообще любую строчку на любой url - его ответственность должна ограничиваться специфическими запросами, имеющими отношение именно к пользователям.
- Необходимости делать ExternalCommunicationManager Singleton-ом нет - у вас в коде нет ничего, что должно явно существовать именно в одном экземпляре. Т.е. можно сделать его синглтоном - но это по сути сэкономит вам максимум одни запрос в `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` на инстанс - т.е. почти ничего.

Comment: да, когда я писал про синглтон, я имел ввиду именно как зависимость в ninject, естественно это будет просто interface и реализация его  в виде байдинга    Bind<IMyManager>().To<MyManager>().InSingletonScope();

UserManager тоже как пример названия, естественно там будут другие менеджеры, а не управление юзером,

Comment: в принципе вопрос в том, что у меня будет около 5 реальных менеджеров, которые будут использовать ExternalCommunicationManager вызовы и как лучше его подключить к этим менеджерам, инджектить как зависимости, или наследовать

Comment: @JULIK это и есть суть ответа - не наследовать, инжектить как зависимость, но не обязательно как синглтон